# AWS S3. How much it costs for sync files from repository that is not mine to my PC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, billing

So I'm very beginner with AWS, and I recently installed the cli program so I can run:

```
aws --version
```

I want to download files from repository that is not mine from:
s3://janelia-cosem/jrc_choroid-plexus-2/jrc_choroid-plexus-2.n5

This repository seems to be "Open Data" (If you go to https://registry.opendata.aws/, and tip "janelia", it appears there)
https://registry.opendata.aws/janelia-cosem/

So I want to run the following command to store the data in my PC

```
aws s3 sync s3://janelia-cosem/jrc_choroid-plexus-2/jrc_choroid-plexus-2.n5 .
```

How much it cost to run this command once? Is it free?

Thank you very much in advance

Additional information:
The size of the folder weights 9GB

The AWS of the bucket seems to be "us-east-1".
I'm from Chile in South America so my local config file says:

```
region = sa-east-1
output = json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ever wondering about costing and the free tiering AWS provides, you may reference [AWS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all)

As for you question regarding the 9GB's of data residing in the bucket location you've provided. You don't pay anything to AWS as long as you download it to your local machine. The cost of the [data transfer and retrieval](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) is not burdened by you- the owner of the account that this bucket resides in will pay the cost.